# iOS: Tabbar - load default state of tab

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need some idea or starting point to the following question:

I have an app which starts with an TabBarView - in some Tabs there are different Views / ViewControllers which are connected by seques.
If the active Tab is changed, i want the (now) open Tab to load the "Start"-View/ViewController of this Tab, not the View/ViewController which was last active on this Tab.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at using the `UITabBarDelegate` method: `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`

combined with the `UINavigationController` method: `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

So when the user selects a tab, you can ensure that the navigation begins from the root controller.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:**

It's not an ideal situation, but you can reference the UITabBarController in the app delegate. E.g.:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Get reference to Tab Bar Controller as the root view
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    // Set Delegate
    tabBarController.delegate = self;

    return YES;
}
```

You can then implement the UITabBarDelegate method similar to:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    // Pop to root if the selected controller is a navigation controller.
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [((UINavigationController *)viewController) popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this though!

Comment: hm, i startet a tabbarapplication, so i dont have a ViewController.m/ViewController.h for the TabBarController... i only have the files for Tab1ViewController and Tab2ViewController - can i add it there?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add some additional code. Hope it helps.

Comment: ok, i have got it: i created a new root view controller for the TabBarController and let it delegate it self. now i can call the didSelectViewController method in the ne RootViewController. thanks for your help!